# How to convert old "plugin.xml" to new "manifest.mf" file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, equinox

How to convert `plugin.xml` file to `manifest.mf` file as some tags like:

```
<runtime>
    <library name="aaa.jar">
        <export name="*"/>
    </library>
<runtime>
```

are seems to be ignored.

Here is some correspondence in the next document, but far from complete reference.

`http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/runtime/adoption.html`

Comment: Another resource: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in the plugin.xml editor.  On the *Overview Tab>Plug-in Content* section there should be a link, "**..., create an OSGi manifest**"

The OSGi manifest is a set of headers describing the bundle, the bundles or packages that are dependencies, and the packages this bundle exports.  ex:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Eclipse UI Tests
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.tests; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 3.6.0.qualifier
Bundle-ClassPath: uitests.jar
Bundle-Activator: org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility.PluginActivator
Bundle-Vendor: Eclipse.org
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.core.expressions,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 ...
Eclipse-AutoStart: true
Export-Package: org.eclipse.ui.tests.api,
 org.eclipse.ui.tests.helpers,
 org.eclipse.ui.tests.menus
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.4
```