# Tools for Eclipse 2.0 plugins upgrade

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

As Eclipse Luna does not support Eclipse 2.0 plugins. Does any one know any tools to upgrade old plugins.

Comment: Eclipse 2.0 is 12 years old, there are not likely to be many tools around now. I am not aware the Luna changes the level of support for old plugins.

Comment: Lund did change the support for 2.x plugins. Equinox moved the support for these into a separate fragment, and by default this fragment is not installed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install support for 2.0 style plugins using `Help > Install New Software`.

Select the 'Eclipse Project Updates' site (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4).

You will find 'Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support' in the 'Eclipse Tests, Examples and Extras' section.

See Eclipse bug [421979](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421979) for some more discussion.

Comment: Thanks Greg, Old style plugins started working again. Do you know of any tools that help us in upgrading these plugins.

Comment: How to convert eclipse 2.0 old style plugin to eclipse 4.4 without the workaround. is there any changes in eclipse 2.0 plugin config files or source files.

Comment: @YogendraSharma See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6809173/2670892 You will need the old style support installed to do this.