# Having trouble converting Java Project to Eclipse Plug-in Development Project

Tags: java, eclipse, pde

I am going through **The Eclipse Debug Framework** tutorial which was presented at Eclipse con 2005 (https://www.eclipsecon.org/2005/tutorials.html). The Zip file (which can be downloaded from the link) contains 7 exercises. For each exercise an initial code base consisting of two plug-ins is provided - *example.debug.core* and *example.debug.ui*.

I tried to import these projects as Plugin and fragments but it doesn't work. (These Projects are not shown as Plugin Projects in the Dialog)

So then I decided to import these projects as **Java Projects** by "File > Import > Existing Project into Workspace" but then I can't seem to convert them to PDE Projects. I tried it by following these instructions [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fpde_actions%2Fconvert_projects.htm).

I am trying to convert these Projects to Plugin Projects because otherwise I can't seem import plugins to the Java classes in these projects

even though I have already added these plugins as Dependencies..

So any Ideas? I am using Eclipse Modeling Tools (Luna). In tutorial they recommend using Eclipse SDK, version 3.1M5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Import > Existing Projects into Workspace' works for me.

For the 'root directory' choose the 'exercise1.1' directory. The two projects should then be listed in the projects list.

**But** these projects are 10 years old and are using the old style plugin.xml format which is not supported by default by current Eclipse builds. This results in lots of import errors.

Comment: Yes these errors  are the reason I was trying to convert these Projects from Java projects to plug-in development projects in the first place. I noticed in Package explorer that Dependant libraries folder doesn't show up even though if I open the plug-in.xml file then under the dependencies Tab I can see that dependencies are corectly set. 

I think the reason for that might be that in the newer Eclipse builds, the dependencies are set by the Manifest.MF file and since it is missing from these projects Eclipse can't seem to find the dependencies inorder to import the required java files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, now it works. This is what I did.

Open plugin.xml file in the editor and Navigate to **Overview Tab**. There under the section **Plugin Content** you would find an option to **Create an OSGi Bundle Manifest** **OR if there is no such option then** a Message asking you to either write a Manifest.MF file manually or to first install **Eclipse 2.0 style plugin support**. (Help> Install New Software, use this update site http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4). You will find 'Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support' in the 'Eclipse Tests, Examples and Extras' section.

checkout this link for more info ([Tools for Eclipse 2.0 plugins upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467105/tools-for-eclipse-2-0-plugins-upgrade))

Once installed old plugins can run and also a **Create OSGi Bundle Manifest** option will appear under **Plugin Content** section if it wasn't there earlier...