# Update Eclipse plugin from 2.x style to 4.x style (plugin.xml to manifest.mf/osgi bundle)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-luna

I have an Eclipse plugin that was originally written (not by me, and I don't have access to the original developer) that I'm trying to update for Eclipse Luna, because it stopped working when my team updated to Eclipse 4.4.

I downloaded the Luna Plugin development version, cleared a few warnings, updated some broken code, fixed a few bugs, and tested with "Run As -> Eclipse Application

[image: Using the Run As -> Eclipse Application menu]

This worked fine: all the views showed up, the preferences pages, etc.

So then I tried to export the plugin so I could test on a fresh installation of vanilla Eclipse Luna. I did that by using the Export Wizard:

[image]

And generated a deployable set of jars with said wizard:

[image]

I copied the generated folder (which contains all the jars appropriately) into the `dropins` folder of my fresh vanilla Eclipse Luna and started it up.

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

[image]

Which led me to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767831/while-installing-plugin-in-eclipse-luna-unable-to-acquire-pluginconverter-serv) and [this Eclipse bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407312), which explains that I have a 2.x style plugin that uses the `plugin.xml` instead of an OSGi style `manifest.mf`. Continuing my search, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809173/how-to-convert-old-plugin-xml-to-new-manifest-mf-file), which was directed at a 3.x version of Eclipse, but I used the 4.x equivalent:

[image]

Which I used with the following options checked:

[image]

And I accepted all the changes in the previous pane after the (long-running) changeset. However, upon deploying to my vanilla install, I got the same error about the plugin converter. That led me back to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767831/while-installing-plugin-in-eclipse-luna-unable-to-acquire-pluginconverter-serv), which recommending installing the Eclipse 2.0 plugin support package. I did so and restarted Eclipse. The error in my error log did stop showing up, however the view/preferences/etc for my plugin are still not showing up. The plugin does show up under Help -> Installation Details -> Plug-ins, but doesn't seem to be interacting at all.

The text of the plugin.xml can be found [here at Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0PzXs7w4). The text of the MANIFEST.MF can by found at [this other Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/d7b66tV3)

Any suggestions for getting my plugin to work through the manual export so the other developers on my team can test my changes before I try releasing the update to the world?

Comment: You probably need to edit the plugin.xml to remove the old 2.0 parts (other parts will still be necessary). The normal plugin export should then be OK.

Comment: How do I tell what the 2.x parts are and which parts are fine for 4.x, and which parts have an equivalent component?

Comment: Add it to the question so we can have a look at it.

Comment: I've added a link to the plugin.xml in the question.

Comment: The plugin.xml looks like it has already been converted.

Comment: Alright, that's good, so why does it spit out the “Unable to acquire PluginConverter service” error, and why aren't the extension points showing up in the views/preferences/right-click menus/etc

Comment: I included the `manifest.mf` in case that helps.